# 403 Forbidden: Able to open uri in browser but not in JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html, web, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to open a (cross domain) uri in my JavaScript code. I'm able to open it if I copy it to my browser and directly open it. However, if I open it in my JavaScript code, I get 403 Forbidden error. Here is my code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.withCredentias = true;
xhr.open('get', uri, 'true');
xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(xhr.response);
}
xhr.send();
```

It doesn't seem like a CORS error, because in the response header I can see my origin host in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin part. I didn't get any CORS error either.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens? Really appreciate your help!

Thanks!

====UPDATE====

Directly from browser (Chrome)

```
Request:
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:host.com
Pragma:no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36

Response:
Cache-Control:max-age=60
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 01 Aug 2016 17:58:20 GMT
Expires:Mon, 01 Aug 2016 17:59:20 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.6 
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

From code

```
Request:
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:host.com
Origin:myhost.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:myhost.com/login
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36

Response:
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:myhost.com
Cache-Control:max-age=60
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 01 Aug 2016 18:20:54 GMT
Expires:Mon, 01 Aug 2016 18:21:54 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.6
```

Comment: Can you add the request/response headers when you call manually the url and when you use an ajax request ?
Also, is `xhr.withCredentias` a typo in your question ? It should be `xhr.withCredentials`.

Comment: yes that withCredentials is a typo, it's correct in my code.

Comment: I'll paste the header later. thanks

Comment: Ever solve this? I am having same problem using electronjs ... works fine when I submit GET request from browser but gives me 403 error when done from Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue where I can submit a GET request just fine from my browser to the URL, but using JavaScript (electron, node.js, net.request) was giving me a 403 error with certain data to that same URL.

I ended looking at the Headers sent by my browser and then just added those same Headers to the Javascript request and then the issue went away.

So this answer is not a pure Javascript answer, but it worked for Electron javascript. I added this in my main.js:

```
const electron = require('electron');
 const { net, session } = electron;


  session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders((details, callback) => {
    details.requestHeaders['Upgrade-Insecure-Requests'] = '1';
    details.requestHeaders['Dnt'] = '1';
    details.requestHeaders['Accept-Encoding'] = 'gzip, deflate, br';
    details.requestHeaders['Accept-Language'] = 'en-US,en;q=0.5';
    details.requestHeaders['Accept'] = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
    details.requestHeaders['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0';
    details.requestHeaders['Connection'] = 'close';
    details.requestHeaders['X-Forwarded-Proto'] = 'http';
    callback({ cancel: false, requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders });
  });

  const request = net.request({
      method: 'GET',
      protocol: 'https:',
      url: 'http s://mydomain.com/somefile.php?data=something&moredata=somethingelse'
   });

  request.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("NetError::: " +err.message);
   });
  
     request.on('response', (_response) => {
    _response.on('end', () => {
      console.log('NetEnd::: END response (no more data).');
    });
    _response.on('data', (_chunk) => {
        console.log("NetStatus::: " + _response.statusCode);
        console.log("NetHeaders::: " + JSON.stringify(_response.headers) );
        console.log("NetBody::: " + _chunk);
    });

 });

 request.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the same problem when I changed User-Agent request header to chrome's standard one.